# Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required" in production but works in local

Tags: java

Getting error while calling a api in production but works in local.

Used same proxy as in local  10.235.88.30 and port 8080

calling through jersey client:-

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = new Client(
   new URLConnectionClientHandler(new HttpURLConnectionFactory() {
        @Override
        public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(final URL url) throws IOException {
            Proxy proxy;


                proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                        new InetSocketAddress("10.235.88.30", 8080));

            return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        }
    }), new DefaultClientConfig());
```

Should return response but getting proxy error.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required"
```

Comment: This is probably an issue with how the proxy is configured and how it authorizes requests originating in different networks. Without a network topology map and detailed proxy configuration there's little hope of anyone here being able to help you beyond pointing to the proxy.

Comment: I don't see an Authenticator, I assume you are using one?